# Android WebView - dont work download file from WebView

Tags: android

I use this Downloadlistener

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDescription,
                                    String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(
                    DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDescription,mimetype);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
            DownloadManager dManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dManager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

But don't work on web site, which I need. If i use for example this url

```
https://www.sendspace.com/....
```

File is normal downloaded.

But if i use this url

```
http://m.slovakrail.sk
```

and i buy ticket and on last site i click on download button, but download doesn't work.
Button code from site is

```
<input type="submit" name="j_idt91:j_idt93:0:j_idt94" value="Stiahnuť cestovný doklad" class="btn" />
```

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the download form uses POST. The only way I found to do this, is to inject JavaScript code using `webView.loadUrl("javascript:...")`, which extracts all the needed information from the form. Then execute the POST request manually in order to download the file. (For example using OkHttp.)

To let the `DownloadManager` know about the downloaded file, you can use the `downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(...)` method.

---

**Example Code (Kotlin)**

```
webView.loadUrl("""
    javascript:(function () {
        let form = document.querySelector("#form-id");
        let inputs = [...form.querySelectorAll("input[type='hidden']")];
        form.querySelector("button.pdfLink[type='submit']").addEventListener(
            'click',
            (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                App.download(JSON.stringify({
                    method: form.method,
                    url: form.action,
                    fields: inputs.map(f => ({key: f.name, value: f.value}))
                }));
            },
            false);
    })()
    """.trimIndent())
```

You also need to add the JS interface to the `WebView`.

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(adapter, "App")
```

The `WebView` JS adapter might look similar to this:

```
class WebViewJsAdapter {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun download(formData: String) {
        val data = JSONObject(formData)
        // 1. download the file
        ...
        // 2. add the downloaded file to the DownloadManager
        //    using `downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(...)`
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaliborFujerik does this help?